# IntelliJ IDEA: scala plug in

Tags: intellij-idea

I am learning scala programming. I've installed intelliJ IDEA and scala plugin as well. I am getting following error:

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/googlecode/sca4idea/SCAProjectComponent.<init>(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;)V @18: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'com/intellij/psi/impl/source/resolve/reference/ReferenceProvidersRegistry' (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'com/intellij/psi/PsiReferenceRegistrar'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @18
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/googlecode/sca4idea/SCAProjectComponent', 'com/intellij/openapi/project/Project' }
    stack: { 'com/googlecode/sca4idea/SCAProjectComponent', uninitialized 10, uninitialized 10, 'com/intellij/psi/impl/source/resolve/reference/ReferenceProvidersRegistry' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab7 0010 2a2b b500 122a bb00 1459 2bb8
    0x0000010: 001a b700 1db5 001f b1                 
 [Plugin: SCA Support]
```

I can't understand what is it.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Praveen Mourya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SCA Support plugin is not the Scala plugin. You can install the Scala plugin if you press the "Install JetBrains plugin" button in Settings | Plugins and search for "Scala" there.

The SCA Support plugin is broken, and you need to uninstall it.

Comment: hi Yole,
I am using gatling stress tool for performance analysis. I want to compile scala code (which is recorded by gatling recorder) on intelliJ idea. I want to know, is there any plugin to compile gatling (scala) code so that it can help me for debugging the errors???

Now, I have to use scala terminal (in intelliJ) or command prompt to execute the scala script.
thanks!